# Add user permissions to an already authorized Android application?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, authorization

I've been testing my app for several days now, but now I want to add new functionalities and I need more permissions from the user. How can I do this if the user already authorized the old permissions? If I add the new permissions to my permissions array, the application stops working.

PD: why am I always getting a -1? Is someone doing that just for fun? :(

If I add more permissions to my permissions array, I get an error when trying to log in:

> An error ocurred, Please try again later

If I delete the new added permissions, the application works again.

#### Answer:

I found out I was using the wrong permissions, now I am using the right ones, that was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding new permissions to an active application isn't a problem. Simply add it. When users download the application, they need to again accept the permissions, like first time.

Comment: so in case i want to use these new permissions i have to uninstall the app and install it again?

Comment: No, the old version will run the old code with the old permissions, the new version will be the new permissions and so have the new capabilites

Comment: I'm trying to test it in the android emulator with eclipse and if i add new permissions the app doesn't work. do you know what the problem might be?